# python unittest.main() does not run the test cases

Tags: python, flask, unit-testing

I am trying to run a very basic test case for my flask application, but when I call unittest.main(), there are zero tests run. I enabled the pdb trace and checked that the imports are working fine. I don't see any other errors or syntax issues.

Here is my test.py file:

```
# test.py

import os
import unittest

from views import app, db
from config import basedir
from models import User

TEST_DB='test.db'

class AllTests(unittest.TestCase):

   # executed prior to each test
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + \
            os.path.join(basedir, TEST_DB)
        self.app = app.test_client()
        db.create_all()

    # executed after each test
    def tearDown(self):
        db.drop_all()

    #each test should start with 'test'
    def test_user_setup(self):
        new_user = User("testuer","test@user.com","testpassword")
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        unittest.main()
```

And here's the result when I call the test script.

```
> python test.py

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the main block i.e., `if __name__ ...`

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I see the issue now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put the `if __name__ == '__main__'` in the body of class `AllTests`, that's why there are no test cases runned.